# Ruby, parse uppercase letters from array of names

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, uppercase

I have a list of names in an array in Ruby:

```
names = ["John Smith","Bob Miller"]
```

So I want to do a regex and get this array:

```
namesRegex = ["JS","BM"]
```

This is, I extract the uppercase characters from the string, merge them and put them in a new array.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What is the problem you're running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple:

```
names.map { |name| name.gsub(/[^A-Z]/, '') }
```

You could very readily construct a less elegant but wholly valid solution to this problem that doesn't even require the use of regular expressions or mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It happens that my lack of experience with the .map function was preventing me to implement the regex for the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 names.map { |name| name.scan(/\b\w/).*'' }
```

Comment: Doesn't `\w` also match non uppercase?

Comment: Yes but at least in the examples, all names/words are starting with an uppercase letter.